# Is it possible to serialize a FIFO in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, fifo

I have a FIFO that gives me a live videostream. All the way, I have to
give it to another application, that is separated like client-server.

Server creates the FIFO where live videostream comes. I can wrap it into
TCP or I can use a .NET shared memory file. I serialized the FIFO object
into bytes, the bytes into ASCII string. On the client side, I deserialized it, I got the fifo, that looks like exactly the same object as in the server.
By debugging, I am able to open it and check its contents. Everything is fine.

I use and endless loop in the server to fill up the serialization.
I read the FIFO in an endless loop, so I cannot return any value from it,
so I use an event to return the FIFO-s periodically.

The problem is, that after a while the returned FIFO is empty except the beginning.

The problem is:
1) I have to supply the FIFO object: succeeded
2) I have to update the contents of the FIFO by serializing it continuously.
3) the 2) overwrites the former object so it can be empty later.

Is that possible at all? How to prevent these problems?
The videostream FIFO is closed source, but I can instantiate it as I know.

Comment: What are you using for a FIFO?  A FIFO you should always be adding to the end and reading from index zero and then removing index zero.  It should work.  You may have issues with under run that you need to test where the serializing is taking longer than the deserialize.

Comment: cogAcqFifo from Cognex. I guessed the memory mapped view size as 8192. If it is 8192 it won't disconnect. Also 16384 is good. Allocation size is the same. But I don't get picture from the stream. I see blank.

I serialize the stream to ASCII. There is an option to serialize it to UTF-8, but why? ASCII is 1 byte, UTF-8 is 2 bytes. UTF-8 may make mistakes...

Comment: UTF-8 is one byte (8 bits).  Don't use ASCII on binary because it removes non-printable characters.  Video is binary so you either use UTF-8 (8 bit binary) or Unicode for 16 bit video.

Comment: I made it with UTF-8. I have the problem, that I have to deserialize it.

`fifo = (Cognex.VisionPro.ICogAcqFifo)CogSerializer.LoadObjectFromStream(memorystream);

myEventArgs args = new myEventArgs();
args.fifo = fifo;
myFIFOEvent.FireFifosChangedEvent(args);`

The problem is now, that my event will be never sent, because the deserialisation takes infinite time, because the FIFO is non-stop built from the other side. How to solve that?

Comment: You need to know the size of the data being received.  So add a byte count to the beginning of each Frame.  Then read Fifo memory stream to end and split at byte count.  So your event would be the memory stream data received event.  After splitting you have to save the remaining data to combine with next chunk.

Comment: I have to use LoadObjectFromStream to reconstruct the object. It cannot handle reading specific byte amounts. I can add bytecounter to the event. Instead of sending FIFO-s, I can send images, but I have to convert them to my specific format to serialize and deserialize and reconvert it to cognex format again.